# What does this snort rule mean?

Tags: snort

`alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"MALWARE-BACKDOOR access remote pc runtime detection - init connection"; flow:to_server,established; content:"|99 F3 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF|"; depth:12; flowbits:set,AccessRemotePC_detection; flowbits:noalert; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:12142; rev:3;)`

Comment: There are many parts here. Please indicate which parts you already understand so that we don't have to explain what `tcp` means, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It will '*alert*' on any TCP connection from an external network to an internal network (DMZ) as long as the content of the packet matches '*99 F3 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF*' (which matches the [BackoffPOS 1.56](https://blog.fortinet.com/post/an-analysis-of-the-backoff-pos-malware) process injection module).

While there is more to the rule; depth, setting the flowbits to a pre-defined class (AccessRemotePC_detection; used for easier reporting) as well as 'classtype', in simplest terms that is your rule breakdown.